# How to design / write "interface-towards-other-APIs" API?

Tags: python, python-2.7, software-design

I currently have 2 APIs that are similar, but they also differ a lot in implementation (lets say they are project-specific), for the sake of explanation I shall call them `API_utilities_project1.py` and `API_utilities_project2.py`.

These APIs are part of bigger framework which also "hosts" scripts that are going to use these APIs. Depending on the defined "project" in the framework, scripts are going to use one of those APIs. **Also scripts can be either project-specific or they can be general/reusable on all projects** (meaning that some scripts won't be used / allowed on some "projects").

I wanted to create a "wrapper" API called `API_utilities.py` around `API_utilities_project1.py` and `API_utilities_project2.py`. This way scripts can import `API_utilities.py` regardless of the project (there is no need to check in scripts which project is defined in the framework and based on that import either first or second API) -> import logic would be handled in `API_utilities.py`.

The problem arises in the fact that both `API_utilities_project1.py` and `API_utilities_project2.py` doesn't need to have functions implemented that are called the same. So I can't just create interfaces towards these functions in 'API_utilities.py'. Only way that works that I have came up with so far is this:

**API_utilities_project1.py**

```
def foo():
    print 'foo'
```

**API_utilities_project2.py**

```
def bar():
    print 'bar'
```

**API_utilities.py**

```
if fwk.project=='project1':
    from API_utilities_project1 import *
elif fwk.project=='project2':
    from API_utilities_project2 import *
else:
    print 'error message / exception or whatnot'


def same():
        print 'same functionality'
```

**script1.py** ('project1' defined in framework)

```
import API_utilities as API

API.foo()
API.same()
```

**script2.py** ('project2' defined in framework)

```
import API_utilities as API

API.bar()
API.same()
```

Is there a cleaner way of writing `API_utilities.py` than using `from ... import *`?

Comment: For this kind of question, requiring Python-2.7 answers seems very odd indeed. Do you have a specific reason to not be using the supported, recommended version of the language?

Comment: We're restricted to this particular version of python.